# Angular 5 Universal render directly form 'dist' instead of 'browser'

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to implement angular universal, for that I have gone through this entire tutorial and setup the app.
https://angular.io/guide/universal

I'm able to build the app but when I serve the app I get an error that it can find any view in 'dist/browser', this is because as, my browser folder is itself not generating. I tried changing the route from 'dist/browser' to just 'dist' and the app worked, although I don't think this is the expected thing to do.

Here's a snippet of my angular-cli.json file if that helps

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular5"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",

      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

How can I get my browser folder to render and make it work properly?

Comment: it may help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1064

Comment: Thanks for searching out but that's completely unrelated

Comment: your build files not generating on browser file ?

Comment: Can you show your .angular-cli.json file?

Comment: @David Updated the question

Comment: @k11k2 I can't see browser folder being generated in my dist folder, according the the tutorial it should be generated, but it's not

Comment: Also in the server folder, I can't see index.html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first app, you actually need to change `outDir`to `dist/browser` instead of just `dist`

Regarding your `index.html` file, it's normal that you don't see it in the `dist/server`folder, your universal server will be using the one for the dist/browser folder

Have a look here, the steps are explained quite clearly
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Comment: Ohh it's working now, I was of the though that I will have a new browser folder generated with all bundled js and index.html, All of it makes clear sense now. Although I was following the tuorial from their offiicial websites - https://angular.io/guide/universal, and this piece of info was not given there.
Thanks!